# Undefined reference function Android NDK

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk

I have `Detection.h` and `Detection.cpp`

```
Detection.h
#ifndef _DETECTION_H_
#define _DETECTION_H_
#include "Accessories.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
     extern "C" {
#endif
int detection(container *ct);
#ifdef __cplusplus
     }
#endif

#endif   

Detection.c
#include "Detection.h"
//Local APIs

//Global API
int detection(container *ct)
{

   return 0;
}
```

I call `detection()` from my `jni.c` as

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "Detection.h"
int *pthread_func(void *proc_ctrl);

JNIEXPORT jint Java_api_Camera_detect
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint do_processing)
{
    int ret;
    int rc;
    void *status;
    pthread_t proc_thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    rc = pthread_create(&proc_thread, NULL, pthread_func, (void *)do_processing);

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_join(proc_thread, &status);
    if (!(int)status){//normal exit
        //pass info to Android UI

        ret = 0;
    }else{//problem
        //pass info to Android UI

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return ret;
}

int *pthread_func(void *proc_ctrl)
{
   int ctrl = (int)proc_ctrl;
   container *ct;
   while(ctrl){
       ct = calloc(1,sizeof (container));
       if(ct == NULL){
           pthread_exit((void*) 1);//Memory allocation error
       }
       ct->numofppl = 0;
       ct->camera_idx = 0;
       ct->frame = camera_get_snapshot();
       //Do detection
       detection(ct);
       if(ct->frame != NULL)
           free(ct->frame);
       if(ct->locs != NULL)
           free(ct->locs);
       free(ct);
   }

   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
   return 0;
}
```

I call `detection()` from `pthread_func()` and I got undefined reference error. What could be wrong?

EDIT1:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=      \
    test1.c       \
    test2.c           \
    test3.cpp

LOCAL_MODULE:= camera

LOCAL_CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wl,-Bsymbolic -DANDROID -DHAVE_ANDROID

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -llog -L $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs -camera_wrapper -lusb

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#########################################################################
# Build libusb_camera_native
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  \
    com_UsbCamera.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= usb_native

LOCAL_CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wl,-Bsymbolic -DANDROID -DHAVE_ANDROID

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs -lusb_camera_wrapper -lusb -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/armeabi -lusb_camera_simple

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Have you compiled detection.c into the same library as jni.c?

Comment: They are in the same folder /jni

Comment: That isn't the same as compiling them both.  What command line do you pass to your compiler?  If you're building using an ide, check that both files are included in the same project.

Comment: yes i use eclipse and they are in the same project and in the same folder. Just that Detection.cpp is cpp file and jni.c is c file. It doesn't matter right?

Comment: So my suspect is that I build with ndk-build. Still checking compiling with ndk-build is the problem.

Comment: What is the content of makefile (.mk file) from jni directory?

Comment: I have updated in EDIT1. Do I need Application.mk? I don't have now.

Comment: @AlexFarber: Thanks. You made me to get idea. I forgot to put Detection.c in LOCAL_SRC_FILES. Thanks. Now no error.